# Durable function long delay before replyaing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

My durable function pauses for a long time before replaying. In the picture you can see the 5-minute delay before rerunning. This is right after starting. I have

```
      "extendedSessionsEnabled": true,
      "extendedSessionIdleTimeoutInSeconds": 30
```

in my host.json file. Sometimes it is only several seconds, 5 min is not uncommon. This is running locally on my machine. There must be a way to speed this up.

[image]

Comment: To try to isolate the issue I created a new project. As soon as I added a couple Activity functions that make a simple database call it slowed way down. One interesting thing is the delay the 1st time. The orchestrator gets called does a couple 1 time things inside a 
`code` if(!context.IsReplaying)

Comment: block. Then it pauses for a few seconds or over 10 minutes. Can't be the size of the return from an activity function since they have not been called yet. I must be doing something wrong. Hard to believe this is the behavior to expect. Any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1148771/durable-function-delay-function-app-in-consumption.html - Check this recently registered issue in MS Q&A Forum which might help your scenario

Comment: Thanks @HariKrishna. I eventually revolved this. Have to admit I have forgotten the details. I should have posted something at the time. It may have simply been deploying the function instead of running on my machine. We also solved another timeout issue by increasing the resources of the function.

Thanks again, this was my 1st post.

Comment: Glad @Kevin for notifying the issue is solved.